# Не находит адрес страници с регистрицией в Django

Tags: html, css, python, django

При нажатии на кнопку регистрации не находиться адрес самой сылки на регистрацию
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

появляеться следующия ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но если продублировать запрос вот так http://localhost:8000/register/register все получаеться

Главный urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('news.urls')),
    path('news/',include('news.urls')),
    path('shop/',include('shop.urls')),
    path('projects/',include('projects.urls')),
    path('register/', include('registration.urls')),
    path('login/', include('registration.urls')),

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

registration urls.py

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('register', views.RegisterFormView, name='RegisterFormView'),
    path('login', views.RegisterFormView, name='RegisterFormView'),
]
```

registration views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import UserRegistrationForm

def RegisterFormView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            new_user.save()
            return render(request, 'register_done.html', {'new_user': new_user})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/registred.html', {'user_form': user_form})
```

registration models.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'email')

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match.')
        return cd['password2']
```

вот сылка при нажатию на которую вы переходите на новый

```
  <li id="Buttons">
  <a href="/register" aligin="center" id="RegisterButton">Зарегестрироваться</a>
  <a href="/login" aligin="center" id="LoginButton">Войти</a>
  <li>
```

Comment: Ну да, вы собственноручно прописали в urls.py именно `/register/register`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Измените Ваш *urls.py* так:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    # path('register/', include('registration.urls')),  <--- Можете удалить
    # path('login/', include('registration.urls')),     <--- Можете удалить
    path('', include('registration.urls')),
    ...
]
```

Теперь пути будут следующими:

- /register
- /login

Comment: Спасибо сработало!!!